# Is it possible to allow docker use the host machines dnses?

Tags: networking, docker, dns, vagrant

Im using Vagrant with Docker and I currently need to reach the host machines dnses from the docker container or even add my custom dns to docker (then i will add my external ip to dns and effect would be the same I think). Is it even possible? I tried to mount /etc directory via *config.yml* as below

```
#directory map
docker_map:
 - "/etc:/etc"
```

and input expecting dns in mounted /etc/hosts file, but it is not working for me (maybe am i doing sth wrong? idk)

I also tried to add host in below field in *config.yml*

```
# factory settings...
docker_hosts:
 - "127.1.2.3 my-dns"
```

but again without success.

I also tried to add --dns parameter to DOCKER_OPTS in /etc/default/docker but It's for sth else I guess...
Could you give me any advice? Thank you.

Comment: did you try `docker run --net=host...`? Ah you use docker-compose, so

Comment: see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. It turned out that it ofc very simple.

Just call:

```
docker ps -a
```

Copy your container id, then:

```
docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash
```

now you are in your container's bash and you can install vim and modify /etc/hosts

Thanks to everyone for help